# Mock specific React hooks in Promises with react-testing-library and ts-jest

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks, ts-jest

I'm trying to test 2 `useState` hooks that get fired during a Promise chain after submitting a form.

All the hooks that are attached to an element (eg email, submit button) work fine, but its the ones that update state in the Promise chain that I don't know how to access in order to mock / test.

```js
    // submit function in ContactForm.tsx
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const data = { firstName, lastName, email, message, subscribe }

        setLoading(true)
        fetchWrapper('/', encode(data))
            .then(() => {
                setStatus(true) // <= throws 'act(() => {...)' error
                props.onSubmit(data) // mock function passed in to check data submitted matches
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setStatus(false) // <= throws 'act(() => {...)' error
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }
```

```js
    // ContactForm.spec.tsx
    import React from 'react'
    import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'
    import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
    import ContactForm, { ContactFormProps } from './ContactForm'
    import { fetchWrapper } from '../../../utils/fetchWrapper'

    jest.mock('../../../utils/fetchWrapper')

    let mockedFetch

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
        mockedFetch = mocked(fetchWrapper)
    })

    it('should submit with firstName, lastName, email, message and subscribe', () => {
        // ASSEMBLE
        const onSubmit = jest.fn()

        const utils = renderContactForm({
            subscribe: false,
            onSubmit,
        })

        const firstName = utils.getByTestId('firstName')
        const lastName = utils.getByTestId('lastName')
        const email = utils.getByTestId('email')
        const message = utils.getByTestId('message')
        const subscribe = utils.getByTestId('subscribe')
        const submit = utils.getByTestId('SEND MESSAGE')

        mockedFetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve())

        // ACT
        fireEvent.change(firstName, { target: { value: 'Clark' } })
        fireEvent.change(lastName, { target: { value: 'Kent' } })
        fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: 'lastson@krypton.com' } })
        fireEvent.change(message, { target: { value: 'I like the sun' } })
        fireEvent.click(subscribe)
        fireEvent.click(submit)

        // ASSERT
        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            firstName: 'Clark',
            lastName: 'Kent',
            email: 'lastson@krypton.com',
            message: 'I like the sun',
            subscribe: true,
        })
    })
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```sh
    Warning: An update to ContactForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser
```

The documentation doesn't seem particularly helpful since they use a simple example, not testing side effects

NOTE: I'd prefer to avoid enzyme if possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to wrap the `fireEvent.click(submit)` in an `act()` from 'react-dom/test-utils`

```js
it('should submit with firstName, lastName, email, message and subscribe', async () => {
    // ASSEMBLE
    const onSubmit = jest.fn()
    const handleCallback = jest.fn()

    const utils = renderContactForm({
        subscribe: false,
        onSubmit,
        handleCallback,
    })

    const firstName = utils.getByTestId('firstName')
    const lastName = utils.getByTestId('lastName')
    const email = utils.getByTestId('email')
    const message = utils.getByTestId('message')
    const subscribe = utils.getByTestId('subscribe')
    const submit = utils.getByTestId('SEND MESSAGE')

    mockedFetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve())

    // ACT
    fireEvent.change(firstName, { target: { value: 'Clark' } })
    fireEvent.change(lastName, { target: { value: 'Kent' } })
    fireEvent.change(email, {
        target: { value: 'lastson@krypton.com' },
    })
    fireEvent.change(message, { target: { value: 'I like the sun' } })
    fireEvent.click(subscribe)

    await act(async () => { // the await / async here is important
        fireEvent.click(submit)
    })

    // ASSERT
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        firstName: 'Clark',
        lastName: 'Kent',
        email: 'lastson@krypton.com',
        message: 'I like the sun',
        subscribe: true,
    })
})
```